# set properties to the child of viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I've extended ViewPager to work out some errors it produces:

```
public class ChildViewPager extends ViewPager {
//work out code
}
```

and now I'm trying to set a view to my Pager

with plain ViewPager it works as usual:

```
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

and this in layout:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="30dp" />
```

but what if I need to cast to a child of a ViewPager,
I certainly can't do it this way :

```
    mViewPager = (ChildViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What errors does `ViewPager` produce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have no missuderstood, you should change

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="30dp" />
```

with

```
<path.to.ChildViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="30dp" />
```

otherwise you will get a `ClassCastException`

```
public class ChildViewPager extends ViewPager {

      public ChildViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);
      }

//work out code
}
```

Comment: it means that you missed to add the constructor ChildViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) . See my edit

Answer (score 1):

In the layout file instead of **android.support.v4.view.ViewPager** add the fully qualified path of your ChildViewPager class.

example:

```
<com.taniasApp.ChildViewPager
 android:id="@+id/pager"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="30dp" />
```

and in the java Activity class:

```
 ChildViewPager mViewPager = (ChildViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Comment: 07-15 17:47:30.975: E/AndroidRuntime(12662): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]

Comment: you need to define a constructor for your ChildViewPager class.